# Critiques for program that integrates functions

Tags: java

The function is entered by the user as a series of coefficients and powers in the form of numerators and denominators.  There is a little error somewhere with negative numbers that I'm working on finding.  Other than that, I just want to know about the coding style.

**Class Integration**

```
package calculus;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Integration 
{
    //create various fields to decide the integration method to be used
    RationalNumbers coeffFraction;
    RationalNumbers powerFraction;
    private final int DIRECT = 1;
    private final int SUBSTITUTION = 2;
    //private final int TRIGONOMETRIC = 3;
    //private final int INTEGRATION_BY_PARTS = 4;
    //private final int LOGARITHMIC = 5;

    //create fields to store various variables needed during the integration process
    private double[] coeffX;
    private double[] powers;
    private int numberOfVariables;  

    //fields to select integration method
    private int integrationMethod;
    private Scanner select;

    //constructor
    /**a constructor that prompts the user to select a number that denotes a certain
     * integration type and matches it to a consequent method that implements the type
     * of integration that has been selected 
     */
    public Integration()
    {
        select = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number denoting the method you want to execute");
        System.out.println("1. Direct Integration \n" +
                           "2. Integration by substitution \n" +
                           "3. Integration of trigonometric functions \n" +
                           "4. Integration by parts \n" +
                           "5. Integration of Logarithmic functions \n");

        //get input
        System.out.print("SELECT: ");
        integrationMethod = select.nextInt();

        switch(integrationMethod)
        {
            case DIRECT:
                directIntegration();
                break;
            case SUBSTITUTION:
                substitutionIntegration();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Sorry that method is yet to be defined");

        }

    }

    /** this method is for integrating simple functions directly.
     * */
    public void directIntegration()
    {
        select = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Direct Integration Selected\n" + 
                            "f(x) = Axa + Bxb + Cxc + Dxd + ... + Nxn");
        System.out.println("\nEnter the number of variables in your function: ");
        numberOfVariables = select.nextInt();

        //initialize necessary arrays to hold all the variable coefficients and powers
        coeffX = new double[numberOfVariables];
        powers = new double[numberOfVariables];

        //initialize the first prompts as 'A' and 'a'
        char coPrompt = 'A';
        char powPrompt = 'a';

        System.out.println("Enter the coefficients and powers");

        //control input coefficients
        System.out.println("COEFFICIENTS");

        for(int counter=0; counter<coeffX.length; counter++, coPrompt++)
        {
            int numerator;
            int denominator;

            System.out.print(coPrompt + ": \n" + 
                                "\tnumerator = ");
            numerator = select.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\tdenominator = ");
            denominator = select.nextInt();

            double coefficient = (double)numerator / denominator;

            coeffX[counter] = coefficient;
        }

        //control input powers
        System.out.println("POWERS");

        for(int counter=0; counter<powers.length; counter++, powPrompt++)
        {
            int numerator;
            int denominator;

            System.out.print(powPrompt + ": \n" + 
                                "\tnumerator = ");
            numerator = select.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\tdenominator = ");
            denominator = select.nextInt();

            double power = (double)numerator / denominator;

            powers[counter] = power;
        }

        //new powers and coefficients after integration
        System.out.print("\nIntegrating ... \n F(x) = ");

        for(int counter = 0; counter<powers.length && counter<coeffX.length; counter++)
        {
            powers[counter] = powers[counter] + 1;
            coeffX[counter] = coeffX[counter] / powers[counter];    

            powerFraction = new RationalNumbers(powers[counter]);
            coeffFraction = new RationalNumbers(coeffX[counter]);


            //code to output 
            if (counter == (coeffX.length - 1) && counter == (powers.length - 1))
            {
                System.out.print(coeffFraction.rationalize() + "x" + powerFraction.rationalize()); 
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(coeffFraction.rationalize() + "x" + powerFraction.rationalize() + " + ");
            }   
        }
    }

    /** this method utilizes substitution to integrate functions.
     * */
    public void substitutionIntegration()
    {
        System.out.println("You have selected substitution integration lakini \nbado sijaitengeneza");
    }
}
```

**Class RationalNumbers**

```
package calculus;

import helper.GreatestCommonDivisor;
public class RationalNumbers 
{
    GreatestCommonDivisor helper;
    private String stringValue;
    private double decimalValue;
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
    private boolean recurring = false;

    public RationalNumbers(double value)
    {
        decimalValue = value;
        stringValue = String.valueOf(Math.abs(decimalValue));
        checkRecurrence();
    }

    //ADDITIONAL CODE
    //method to check whether the value passed is recurring or not
    public void checkRecurrence()
    {       
        if(stringValue.length() > 4)
        {
            if(stringValue.charAt(3) == stringValue.charAt(4))
            {
                recurring = true;
            }
        }
    }


    public void ratios()
    {
        int countDecimalPlaces = 0;

        //code to extract recurring numbers and add their behavior
        if(recurring)
        {
            int firstValue = (int)(100 * decimalValue);
            int secondValue = (int)(1000 * decimalValue);

            denominator = 900;
            numerator = secondValue - firstValue;
        }
        else
        {
            for(int counter = 2; counter<stringValue.length(); counter++)
            {
                countDecimalPlaces++;
            }

                denominator = (int)(Math.pow(10, countDecimalPlaces));

            if(decimalValue >= 1)   //setting of numerator for improper fractions   
            {
                numerator = (int)(decimalValue * denominator);
            }

            else
            {
                numerator = Integer.parseInt(stringValue.substring(2));
            }
        }
    }

    public String rationalize()
    {
        int[] rations = new int[2];
        String fraction;

        ratios();
        helper = new GreatestCommonDivisor(numerator, denominator);

        if(decimalValue<0)  //cater for decimal numbers inputed
        {
            rations[0] = (numerator / helper.gcd()) * (-1);         
        }
        else
        {
            rations[0] = numerator / helper.gcd();
        }

        rations[1] = denominator / helper.gcd();

        if(rations[1] == 1)
        {
            fraction = String.valueOf(rations[0]);
        }   

        else
        {
            fraction = (rations[0] + "/" + rations[1]);
        }

        return fraction;
    }
}
```

**Class GreatestCommonDivisor**

```
package helper;
/**This class has a constructor that accepts two values and
 * then implements the gcd() method to find the greatest common 
 * divisor of the values*/
public class GreatestCommonDivisor 
{
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;
    private int gcd = 1;

    public GreatestCommonDivisor(int value1, int value2)
    {
        numerator = value1;
        denominator = value2; 
    }

    public int gcd()
    {
        int dividend = 2;

        //check here for the problem when you are freshazamiz
        while(dividend <= Math.min(numerator, denominator))
        {
            while(numerator % dividend == 0 && denominator % dividend == 0)
            {
                numerator = numerator / dividend;
                denominator = denominator / dividend;
                gcd = gcd * dividend;
            }

            dividend++;
        }

        return gcd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you have commented out code? If you do need it please throw it away. Leaving it commented out does not help.

I'd also replace all these constants with an `Enum` to improve readability and maintainability of the code. With the `Enum` you can also rely on the compiler to check that you use a valid value.

```
private final int DIRECT = 1;
private final int SUBSTITUTION = 2;
private final int TRIGONOMETRIC = 3;
private final int INTEGRATION_BY_PARTS = 4;
private final int LOGARITHMIC = 5;
```

In order to have a more object oriented solution, I'd replace the `switch` that you use to choose the integration method with [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) or with a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

I'd also avoid mixing methods that handle input/output and methods that does the computation of the result. Consider having I/O in a separate class that the one actually doing the integration.

Is your `RationalNumbers` class representing a single number or a set of number? If it has to represent a single number please call it `RationalNumber`.

I'd introduce a `Fraction` data type and use it to introduce the output of the `rationalize` method. Why should it return a `String`?

Comment: Fraction data type? I do not think i am familiar with that. i will rectify the code appropriately however I just want to point out that for proper output, I needed to the rationalize method to return a string rather than an array(because it has to return 2 values).

Comment: I was suggesting you to create a new `Fraction` class to represent mathematical fractions. It should have two attributes (The numerator and the dividend) and it should solve cleanly the issue you have returning two values.

Comment: Thank you. Polymorphism vs switch, I/O vs Computation, Naming Conventions & style (I cant beleive I missed this) and Fraction class. Thank you Mario for your pointers and help.

Comment: @mariosangiorgio No need for a `Fraction` type. `RationalNumber` is OP's fraction type. `rationalize` is just a bad name for `toString`.